# Fetching data from mulitple tables using zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to construct SQL query using Zend Framework. Here is my SQL query statement:

```
    SELECT of.order_Id, of.subtotal, of.status, c.name
    FROM order_form of, customer c
    WHERE c.customer_Id = of.customer_Id
```

However, when I tried to implement it in Zend Framework, an error message is displayed. Here is my query statement using Zend Framework.

```
$query = $db->select()
            ->from(array('c' => 'customer'), 'name')
            ->where('c.customer_Id = ?', $customer_Id)
            ->join('order_form', 'order_form.customer_Id = customer.customer_Id', array('order_Id', 'subtotal', 'status'))
            ->order("order_form.order_Id ASC");
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, the problem is resolved, sorry for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in my part. Simply change `customer.customer_Id` to `c.customer_Id` in the `join` clause

```
$query = $db->select()
            ->from(array('c' => 'customer'), 'name')
            ->where('c.customer_Id = ?', $customer_Id)
            ->join('order_form', 'order_form.customer_Id = c.customer_Id', array('order_Id', 'subtotal', 'status'))
            ->order("order_form.order_Id ASC");
```

Sorry for any inconvenience caused.